# Некорректная работа перемотки влево у карусели (слайдера)

Tags: javascript

Делаю маленькую карусель (слайдер). 
Посередине главное изображение, внизу идет список из маленьких. 
[image: пример]
Но, не получается корректно сделать перемотку влево. 
Когда доходит до первого изображения, и при перемотке дальше должно отобразиться последнее (начать круг по новой).

При прокрутке вправо все понятно.... как назад листать, не могу сообразить.
Получаю нужные элементы:

```
const mainImg = document.querySelector(".main-picture img");
const listImgAll = document.querySelectorAll(".list-images>li>a>img");
const arrowLeft = document.querySelector(".control-left");
const arrowRight = document.querySelector(".control-right");
```

Смена изображений при нажатии на маленькие изображения (из списка):

```
listImgArea.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  let target = event.target;
  if (target.tagName != 'IMG') return;
    mainImg.src = target.src
}, false);
```

Прокрутка в право (и дальше по кругу) :

```
arrowRight.addEventListener("click", function() {
  for (let i=0; i < listImgAll.length; i++){
    // console.log(i);
    if (i===listImgAll.length-1){
      mainImg.src = listImgAll[0].src
    }
    if (mainImg.src === listImgAll[i].src) {
      mainImg.src = listImgAll[i+1].src;
      break
    }
  }
}, false);
```

Прокрутка влево (тут нужна помощь) :

```
arrowLeft.addEventListener("click", function() {
  for (let i=0; i < listImgAll.length; i++){
    // if (mainImg.src === listImgAll[0]){
    //   console.log('test');
    // }
    if (mainImg.src === listImgAll[i].src){
      mainImg.src = listImgAll[i-1].src;
      break
    }
  }
}, false);
```

При клике делаю просто listImgAll[i-1], все ок, елси листаю не с первого изображения, но когда доходит до первого- выдает ошибку: 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined at HTMLAnchorElement."
Как правильно создать условие, что бы при попадании на первое изображение в списке - нужно начинать листать список изображений с конца (по кругу).

[image: пример]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка случается из-за того, что на первой картинке `i` становится меньше нуля, нужно этот момент контролить, например вот так:

```
arrowLeft.addEventListener("click", function() {
for (let i=0; i < listImgAll.length; i++){

  if (mainImg.src === listImgAll[i].src){
    // eсли i равно нулю, меняем значение на величину массива
    // i-1 будет индексом последнего элемента
    if (i === 0) i = listImgAll.length;

    mainImg.src = listImgAll[i-1].src;
    break
  }
}
```

}, false);